# Users have to login twice when using loginasanotheruser

Tags: development

We have multiple users who can use the same computer (Let's say simple users and managers) and we have a document library that is only authorized for managers. The library is reachable with a link in the quicklaunch navigation.

The link in the quicklaunch is using `_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true&Source=%2ftest%2fLists%2fDocumentManager` to force the user to reenter credentials because it is possible that a simple user use the computer with the login of the manager. But when the user click the link, he is prompted 2 times.

I tried to analyse with fiddler what is happening but I didn't find anything. The user trying to log in has full right access (SiteCollection administrator).

Is there another way (JS or applicative page) to force the users to reenter their credentials to access a lists ?